# When number is negative, save 0 (mysql)

Tags: mysql

i have a field in the db that stores doubles, what i want to achieve is that, if the number that is going to be saved, is negative, then it should save 0 instead. I dont know if i shoud define this in the query, or if there is a way to set it like that in the db itself. I will appreciate if someone can give me an answer; by the way im using mysql.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the MySQL `IF` syntax:

```
UPDATE table SET column=IF(value<0, 0, value) WHERE ...
```

More on the `IF` syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/if.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use MySQL's IF() function, which takes the form:

if(expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN) VALUES (IF(my_value < 0, 0, my_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the values in the table, then you can update the negative ones:

```
update table
   set value = 0
   where value < 0;
```

This is potentially much more efficient than using `if` or `case` (which is preferable to `if` because `case` is ANSI standard).

If you want to adjust the values when they are going into the table, then you need to create a `before update` trigger and a `before insert` trigger to fix the values.

However, you might be able to get what you want just by using a view:

```
create view v_table as
    select col1, col2, col3, (case when value < 0 then 0 else value end) as value
    from table;
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help guys, but i found another an easier solution, i use the mysql function greatest, example: =>>> INSERT into tbl_betrate GREATEST($val1 - '$decrease', 0) ... this will return 0 if the number is negative...i hope it serves to someone else that is in the same difficulty...and if my approach is not good enough please be free to correct me...it works, but may not be the best...